# Only the http:// and www url does not redirect to https

Tags: https, redirect

I have a Wordpress site which was migrated with some matters.
The goal is force to redirect always with `https` and `www`.

- http://caravelleconsulting.com     ->  https://www.caravelleconsulting.com/
- http://www.caravelleconsulting.com ->  https://www.caravelleconsulting.com/
- https://caravelleconsulting.com    -> https://www.caravelleconsulting.com/

That works EXCEPT for http://www.caravelleconsulting.com which redirects to http://www.caravelleconsulting.com without `https`

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Redirection to HTTPS AND WWW
# version 1
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^caravelleconsulting\.com$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.caravelleconsulting\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
# Version 2 - same result than the first version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


# send to router
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I found a third solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130006/redirect-to-https-and-www-with-one-301-redirect#answer-43131152) but when I test with http://www.redirect-checker.org, I got a 301 Moved Permanently loop.

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found my solution based on several answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
#avoid loop - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


# send to router
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```